# South African citizen in UK on a student visa (less than 90 days left) travelling to Schengen Area

Tags: visas, schengen, uk, south-african-citizens

I am a South African citizen on a Tier 4 UK student visa which expires at the end of August. I am hoping to go to the Schengen area (Italy and then France) from 28 June to 4 July, but I noticed that the website says that I need to have a:

"UK Residence permit valid for at least 90 days beyond the return date of the trip to the Schengen Area"

Obviously, my UK student visa will expire before 90 days after I return.

My question is: are they very strict on thisrequirement ? I have my return flights booked back to the UK and will possibly have my flights back to South Africa booked as well.

Any advice or experience on this? Thanks so much!!!

EDIT: I would be perfectly fine with a short stay (i.e. 15 or 30 day visa), single entry visa.

EDIT: Would giving a full itinerary with tour bookings etc prove my bone fides as a tourist and not someone who is seeking to overstay their visa?

Am I likely to have my visa refused?

Comment: Well... yes, they are strict about this sort of thing, especially with visas near to expiry.  You would expect the carrier to prevent you from boarding the flight.

Comment: Is there any chance they would issue a short (30 day) visa?

Comment: Yes, you can ask for a single-entry, time-limited visa. It will cost the same and require the same application. But absolutely yes. You can also ask for a territorial restriction as well. Same price, same application, same processing, etc.

Comment: If it helps the application to specify a single short visa, that would be brilliant - I literally only need the schengen visa for the relevant 7 days.

Comment: Edit your question to include the new info and someone will be along to put in a fleshed-out "formal" answer for you. Thanks